# Leaking of infrastructure concern into Domain via Akka PersistenceActor

Tags: actor, akka-persistence

The domain model while practicing DDD should be rich without no infrastructure concerns. *Repository* is such an example. Having a *Enterprise Bus* is also. The domain should not depends on such implementation. The app service may be doing that job.

Akka actors which is promoted to be the same as aggregates in DDD is appropriate, but having a [PersistentActor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence.html) is leaking the infrastructure concern into the domain.

An aggregate like **OrderManager** derived from a **PersistentActor** will include both the domain concepts and the persistence concerns. How to make a separation where by moving the infrastructure concerns out from domain?

Is having two actors, one actor for **OrderManager** which is derived from **ReceiveActor** and the other from the **PersistentActor** a solution?